# How to download a file with authentication?

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I'm working with the website 'musescore.com' that has many files in the '.mxl' format that I need to download automatically with Python.

Each file on the website has a unique ID number. Here's a link to an example file:

```
https://musescore.com/user/43726/scores/76643
```

The last number in the URL is the id number for this file. I have no idea where on the website the mxl file for score is located, but I know that to download the file, one must visit this url:

```
https://musescore.com/score/76643/download/mxl
```

This link is the same for every file, but with that file's particular ID number in it. As I understand it, this url executes code that downloads the file, and is not an actual path to the file.

Here's my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://musescore.com/score/76643/download/mxl'
user = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'

r = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password), stream=True)
with open('file.mxl', 'wb') as f:
  for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
    f.write(chunk)
```

This code downloads a webpage saying I need to sign in to download the file. It is supposed to download the mxl file for this score. This must mean I am improperly authenticating the website. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing an `auth` parameter to `get`, you're attempting to utilize [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication), which is not what this particular site uses. You'll need to use an instance of `request.Session` to post to their login endpoint and maintain the cookie(s) that result from that process.

Additionally, this site utilizes a csrf token that you must first extract from the login page in order to include it with your post to the login endpoint.

Here is a working example, obviously you will need to change the username and password to your own:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://musescore.com/user/login')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
csrf = soup.find('input', {'name': '_csrf'})['value']

s.post('https://musescore.com/user/auth/login/process', data={
    'username': 'herp@derp.biz',
    'password': 'secret',
    '_csrf': csrf,
    'op': 'Log in'
})

r = s.get('https://musescore.com/score/76643/download/mxl')

print(f"Status: {r.status_code}")
print(f"Content-Type: {r.headers['content-type']}")
```

Result, with content type showing it is successfully downloading the file:

```
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/vnd.recordare.musicxml
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Make sure to look for the path of csrf correctly, other websites may have it under `csrf_token`, just replace `_csrf` for `csrf_token`.